# Rails jQuery fade out one element, fade in another element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

What I want to do is fadeOut the #new_link element, and after that is faded out, to then fade in this form. Here is what I have so far:

```
$('#new_link').fadeOut().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

This appropriately fade's out the new_link element, and displays the content, but it seems that no matter where I put the fadeIn function, it makes the form element not render.  Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$form = $('<%= j render("form") %>').hide();
$('#new_link').after($form);
$('#new_link').fadeOut(function() { $form.fadeIn() });
```

Comment: Wow!  I've been trying to figure this out for  a long time!  Perfect!  Thanks so much!